# ImportError: No module named services Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, backend

I installed python 2.7 alongside my mac. I have a project running using Django v1.9.4.
Unfortunately `manage.py runserver` is throwing an error while running failed because it couldn't find module named services.

From a shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named services
```

I'm wondering what should be done here to install this module.

Comment: What does your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` look like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'services' is your project's module.
Maybe you should set the PYTHONPATH environment to make python find your module.
If the module is in current directory, you can run the project like this:
    export PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH
    manage.py runserver